# DNS-SD registration of "printer_queue1" failed with -65548

Tags: linux, networking, dns, cups, mdns

I'm using Linux [ RHEL 5] , our team manages printing via this server , the printing uses CUPS 1.3.7 .

We experienced very reliable printing for more than a year and a half , but since last 2 weeks our printing is delayed intermittently and queues are getting disabled , we need to use scripts to enable it by running cronjobs .

While we checked the error logs , it showed the below message a lot of times for multiple queues 
"**DNS-SD registration of "printer_queue1" failed with -65548**"
We have etc/resolv.conf file with the correct active DNS server's IP .
When we do NS look-up as a loop continuously, there is no lapse and also it shows the primary DNS is used to resolve the name to IP .

No changes are performed to the CUPS or at network level .
Is there a possibility for cups to multicast [mdns] the hostname, in order to resolve the IP instead of using the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

when I grep in `ps -ef` command to get the process of connectivity

```
socket://hostname.site.company.com:9100 1632881 User1 Local Downlevel Document 1 job-uuid=urn:uuid:973f8362-7329-3ffe-79cc-e956ab07c6b9 /var/spool/cups/d1632881-001
```

Please share your thoughts like why the -65548 error occurs and possible chances of delay within CUPs processing a job or queues getting disables intermittently .

Answer (score 3):

The -65548 error refers to name conflicts. If you look at the mDNSResponder source, you can see that this error indicates that the name is already registered.

I would check to see if you have more than one printer queue on the network with that name that could be colliding. Also make sure you're not running more than one multicast dns service on the system (avahi vs. mDNSRepsonder)